# JavaFX set mouse hidden when idle

Tags: java, javafx

How can i hide the mouse on JavaFX application, when the user is idle, lets say for 1 sec ? and show it again when the mouse move?

I have this part of code

```
scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
```

But i do not know how to link it to idle time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
PauseTransition idle = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
idle.setOnFinished(e -> scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE));
scene.addEventHandler(Event.ANY, e -> {
    idle.playFromStart();
    scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
});
```

This creates a one-second pause. When the user performs any action, the pause is restarted and the cursor set to the default. If the pause finishes, which can only happen if it wasn't restarted for the whole duration (i.e. if the user did nothing for a second), then the cursor is set to `NONE`.

Comment: This works however If the cursor is on a control it does not work, for example having the cursor over a button doesn't trigger this. Any help?